# Integrate GoDaddy Office365 domain with Azure Active Directory

Tags: microsoft-office-365, godaddy, entra-id

We have an Office365 domain hosted at GoDaddy, using GoDaddy's Office365 hosted implementation. I've connected this domain to Azure Active Directory, following the basic instructions here (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started) as best as I was able. Accounts seem to be syncing (one-way), so I'm confident that the basic configuration is correct.

But when I try to join an (existing) Azure VM running Windows Server 2012 (in an AD-enabled VNet), using an account that I've added to the "aad dc administrators" group, I get the error, "The user name or password is incorrect".

Similarly, I'm not sure how to go about joining on-premise machines to that AD domain. The domain controllers are (of course) sitting in the VNet, behind a VPN, and are (so far as I can tell) accessible only if my local machine knows how to get to that domain's controllers. But since they're the only DNS servers that know about themselves - and since they're behind a VPN - how does my local machine know how to connect to and join that domain? I tried it, and it seemed to work - my laptop is now a member of our Azure AD domain - but when I try to login using my domain account, I get an error the effect of, "Can't do that right now."

Sorry if these are basic issues - my AD management days are probably 15 years in the past, and lots has changed since then.

Comment: "If your organization has a cloud-only Azure AD tenant, users that need to use Azure AD Domain Services must change their passwords." https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started-password-sync

Comment: @Paul - Thanks, tried that - didn't seem to work. Still got the "Username or password is incorrect' error when trying to join a machine to the domain.

Comment: I also tried to add my azure VM into Azure AD DS . Have you checked DNS server setting : click your azure directory name-->configure-->scroll down to "domain services" , it should list the DNS server IP address. This IP should be the DNS server IP of VMs which needs to be joined to Azure AD DS .

Comment: In addition, the DNS server IP address should be 'pingable' from VMs under same virtual network.

Comment: I also changed the password for my test account through the web page : "http://myapps.microsoft.com", then this account can logon azure VM successfully .